# Team Foundation Server with Blackberry Project in Eclipse not synching correctly

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, tfs, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse 3.5.2 with Team Foundation Everywhere plugin (TFS plugin).

I have several blackberry projects in my eclipse workspace which i have successfully added to TFS. However I have found that the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml is not being updated in TFS when i make changes to it.

For example when I change the name and version number of the application TFS see's no change in the file so when I check in the server version is still the old data. We are developing on several machines so having changes i do on my machine not propigate to the others is causing problems.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I can see from visual inspection of the .xml file that it is changing but why does TFS not considered it any different?

I have tried manually 'check out for edit' on the file, then change the name and check it back in. But it sees that there are no changes and disreguards my checkin.

Thanks,
Stephanie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone else runs into this, it seems that the eclipse plugin for TFS is having issues with comparing XML files. If i manually change the XML contents and save to disk. Then do 'Compare local with server version' it will say 'files are identical'. What I ended up doing was removing the file from TFS. Doing my edits on a local version then readding it. It gets the updates into TFS so the whole team gets the same version. Wish it would just work though because now everytime we want to change anything in an xml file its a long process instead of being a simple update/checkin